# what is the use build gradle in resolutionStrategy in kotlin library

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in kotlin library. I am building a library for first time. I created a project in kotlin multiplatfrom in intellj and some files are auto-created . I see in my `setting.gradle.kts` I have `resolutionStrategy`inside that gradle line which I don't understand

**setting.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2") // what is the use of 4.1.2?
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "abc"
```

I thing `4.1.2` is very old and can we update to latest version?

```
useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.21"
    id("com.android.application")
}

group = "com.abc"
version = "0.0.1"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    sourceSets {
        val ktorVersion = "2.0.0"
        val commonMain by getting
        val androidMain by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
                dependsOn(commonMain)
                iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
                iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
                iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 21
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.abc.kotlinmultiplatform"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
    }
    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```